# Folder scanning script, want to surround all files with <files> </files> but not the folders

Tags: php, xml

I want my script to put  around all the files in a folder, but not around folders in the folder, this is the code I have atm:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
$folder = scandir($dir);
echo "<folder name='".$dir."'>";
foreach($folder as $file){
    if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) {            
            listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$file);        
        }
        else{
         echo '<file>'.$file.'</file>';
        }  
    }   
}
echo "</folder>";
}
```

I want an output like this:

```
<folder name='appdata'>
    <folder name='appdata/assets'>
        <files>
            <file>New Text Document - Copy (2) - Copy.txt</file>
            <file>New Text Document - Copy (2).txt</file>
            <file>New Text Document - Copy.txt</file>
            <file>New Text Document.txt</file>
        </files>
        <folder name='appdata/assets/audio'>
            <folder name='appdata/assets/audio/frl'>
                <files>
                    <file>New Microsoft Excel Worksheet - Copy (2).xlsx</file>
                    <file>New Microsoft Excel Worksheet - Copy - Copy.xlsx</file>
                    <file>New Microsoft Excel Worksheet - Copy.xlsx</file>
                    <file>New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx</file>
                </files>
            </folder>
        </folder>
    </folder>
</folder>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried it and it looks ok. What is the problem? What output do you get.

Comment: I suggest using an XML Api like, DOM that would allow to store the nodes and add data to them.

Comment: @Seb I want the files the be surrounded with <files> </files> tags, atm they dont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. It's just one possible solution, but you will also get all folders at the beginning:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
   $folder = scandir($dir);
   echo "<folder name='".$dir."'>";
   $files = array();
   foreach($folder as $file){
       if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
           if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) {            
               listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$file);        
           }
        else{
            $files[] = $file;
        }  
    }
    if (!empty($files)) {
       echo "<files>";
       foreach ($files as $_file) {
           echo '<file>'.$_file.'</file>';
       }
       echo "</files>";
    }   
}
   echo "</folder>";
}
```

Comment: Moved the !empty $files foreach out of the first foreach to work properly, thanks